# Lower abs not hurting

Tags: workout-routines, abdominals, back-pain

I am doing excercise cruches for abs but my upper and near chest only hurt while lower down I don't see any effect at all. Why is this are abs are worked out separately for lower middle and upper ? Moreover I am feeling backpain while doing crunches just behind upper abs is that normal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your focus isn’t to train the upper / mid / lower abs -- crunches only target the rectus abdominis. In addition, **crunches places unnecessary strain on your back**, which would explain the LBP.  Try to think of your core as *layers* rather than *sections*.

The core and low back muscles work together. The ***transverse abdominis*** (TrA) is the ***first muscle that fires literally every time you move***. If you can keep your (TrA) correctly activated you’re on the way to more efficient movement, a stronger body, decreasing your pain etc.

---

**Here’s a better alternative to crunches**

The plank with hip flexion adds ***emphasis to key foundation areas*** including your **shoulders, torso, and deep spinal stabilizers**.

---

> ### Planks with Hip Flexion

[image]

1. Start in a push-up position with your hands beneath your shoulders
   and feet shoulder-width apart.
2. Keeping your hips and torso still, draw one knee toward your chest.
3. Return to the starting position and repeat with the opposite leg.

Answer (score 0):

This is because crunches mainly target the upper abs.

To target the lower abs I suggest doing hanging leg raises or reverse crunches. If hanging leg raises are to hard for you at the moment you can also do leg raises while laying on the floor. Static holds (like planking for instance) will also develop your abs overall.

About the pain as you describe it, does that feel like pain in any muscle or is your back hurting from laying on the ground? I never felt anything like that before while doing crunches.